# Why Fortran/gfortran assume the UNKNOWN type?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a grammar question about Fortran.
It seems that Fortran (or gfortran?) cannot assume a returning value of a function defined in an interface block in an abstract interface.
I tried to compile the following codes by gfortran (version 9.4.0).

abstract_class.f90:

```
module module_abstract_class
    implicit none

    type, public, abstract :: abstract_class
        contains
        procedure(method_interface), pass(self), deferred :: method
    end type

    abstract interface
        pure function method_interface(self, func, a, b) result(ret)
            import abstract_class
            class(abstract_class), intent(in) :: self
            real                 , intent(in) :: a, b
            real                              :: ret

            interface
                pure function func(a, b) result(ret)
                    real, intent(in) :: a, b
                    real             :: ret
                end function
            end interface

        end function
    end interface
end module
```

extend_class.f90:

```
module module_extend_class
    use module_abstract_class

    implicit none

    type, extends(abstract_class) :: extend_class
        contains
        procedure, public, pass(self) :: method
    end type

    contains

    pure function method(self, func, a, b) result(ret)
        class(extend_class), intent(in) :: self
        real               , intent(in) :: a, b
        real                            :: ret

        interface
            pure function func(a, b) result(ret)
                real, intent(in) :: a,b
                real             :: ret
            end function
        end interface

        ret = func(a, b)
    end function method
end module
```

main.f90:

```
program i_love_fortran
    use module_extend_class

    type(extend_class) :: e

    print *, e%method(add, 1, 2)

contains

    pure function add(a, b) result(ret)
        real, intent(in) :: a, b
        real             :: ret
        ret = a + b
    end function
end Program i_love_fortran
```

shell:

```
gfortran abstract_class.f90 extend_class.f90 main.f90
```

But, I could not compile this code due to the following errors.

---

gfortran abstract_class.f90 extend_class.f90 main.f90
extend_class.f90:8:17:

```
8 |         procedure, public, pass(self) :: method
  |                 1
```

Error: Argument mismatch for the overriding procedure ‘method’ at (1): Type mismatch in argument 'func' (UNKNOWN/REAL(4))
extend_class.f90:6:49:

```
6 |     type, extends(abstract_class) :: extend_class
  |                                                 1
```

Error: Derived-type ‘extend_class’ declared at (1) must be ABSTRACT because ‘method’ is DEFERRED and not overridden
main.f90:2:8:

```
2 |     use module_extend_class
  |        1
```

Fatal Error: Cannot open module file ‘module_extend_class.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

---

I think "func" defined in "method" should be REAL(4).
Why does Fortran/gfortran assume that "func" is UNKNOWN type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `func` is just another `abstract interface`, because id defines what the actual pure function will be like when the function called. So, you should include it just as also an `abstract interface` and make it public so other modules can access it.
Then, you reference it as a function dummy argument using

```
procedure(func_template) :: func
```

This now works:

```
module module_abstract_class
    implicit none

    type, public, abstract :: abstract_class
        contains
        procedure(method_interface), pass(self), deferred :: method
    end type

    interface
    end interface

    abstract interface
        pure function func_template(a, b) result(ret)
            real, intent(in) :: a, b
            real             :: ret
        end function func_template
    
        pure function method_interface(self, func, a, b) result(ret)
            import abstract_class,func_template
            class(abstract_class), intent(in) :: self
            real                 , intent(in) :: a, b
            procedure(func_template)          :: func
            real                              :: ret

        end function
    end interface
end module


module module_extend_class
    use module_abstract_class

    implicit none

    type, extends(abstract_class) :: extend_class
        contains
        procedure, public, pass(self) :: method
    end type

    contains

    pure function method(self, func, a, b) result(ret)
        class(extend_class), intent(in) :: self
        real               , intent(in) :: a, b
        procedure(func_template)        :: func
        real                            :: ret

        ret = func(a, b)
    end function method
end module


program i_love_fortran
    use module_extend_class

    type(extend_class) :: e

    print *, e%method(add, 1.0, 2.0)

contains

    pure function add(a, b) result(ret)
        real, intent(in) :: a, b
        real             :: ret
        ret = a + b
    end function
end Program i_love_fortran
```